# When should we use NodeJS and when should we use MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

As a new developer, I am always confused about using NodeJS and MongoDB. So I hope I will get an actual answer. Thanks...

Comment: Nodejs is a plattform to write js code. MongoDB is a database witch can be used with node.js

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB and NodeJS are two different technologies. MonogDB is a database system which gives you a chance to efficiently store documents in a database and to perform operations like data updates, or to search documents by some criterias.

NodeJS's responsibilty is especially to execute your application.

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs is a Javascript engine that you can write any application you want with (by programming in the Javascript language).  It runs your Javascript code.  Most commonly, it is used to build servers that can respond to web requests, though it can be used for lots of other types of code too.

MongoDB is a database engine.  Code within some application or server uses MongoDB to save, query or update data in a database.  There are many web servers built with nodejs that will then use MongoDB for storing data.

MongoDB offers an API library that runs within a Nodejs application to give you programmatic access to MongoDB so you can create databases and then add, query, update or delete data from the MongoDB database.  MongoDB also has API libraries for other programming environments such as Python, Java, etc...

These two technologies are for different parts of a typical web server system.  You don't substitute one for the other.  Instead, you can use them together.

> When should we use Nodejs?

Any project needs a programming environment and a runtime library that offers you basic programming tools/support and can compile and/or interpret your code.  Nodejs is such as tool for the Javascript programming language.  There are other similar tools for other languages such as Python, Java, PHP, C#, C++, Go, etc...

So, if you want to write some kind of stand-alone program or server in Javascript, then you can use nodejs for it.

> When should we use MongoDB?

If your application needs the ability to persistently store data in a way that you can efficiently query or update it later, then you would typically use some form of database.  There are dozens of popular databases.  MongoDB is one such database.  MariaDB, MySql, CouchDB, DynamoDB (on AWS), Postgres are examples of other databases.  Different databases have different strengths (things they are best at) and different ways of using them so it's a whole different question to choose the right/best database for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Blog link](https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/why-the-hell-would-i-use-node-js#:%7E:text=js%20used%20for%3F-,Node.,push%2Dbased%20architectures%20in%20mind.) that will tell you when you should use NodeJS.

Here is [another link](https://www.guru99.com/mongodb-vs-mysql.html) to understand when you should use mongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Well, NodeJS and MongoDB are two different process. Here I tried to explain as simpler as possible:

> NodeJS

Shortly we can say, NodeJS is a JavaScript runtime environment. It's actually helps JavaScript to run outside of server. It's used in server side development.

> MongoDB

But, MongoDB is NoSQL database which is document oriented. It represents data as of JSON documents. It's used for store data.

> Summary

The summary is MongoDB is a database where we can store data and NodeJS helps us to to connect our client site to database by it's server site.

> Example:

Suppose you are building a website and you need a database to store the data or information so here you can use MongoDB but to be connected with MongoDB you need a connector, so here you can use NodeJS which will help your website to run outside of server.

Answer (score 0):

**Nodejs:** Node.js is an interpreter or runtime/ running environment for JavaScript. built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine. responsibility is especially to execute your application.
**MongoDB:** is a No-SQL database for storing data. when you need high availability of data with automatic, fast, and instant data recovery.